# React useEffect loop

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a React shopping cart, and I am having a locked loop problem with an useEffect hook.

Initially, I use an useEffect to fetch id's and quantities of products in the cart and store these values in a state variable array of objects named *shopCart*:

```
// fetches the id's and quantities of all products in the user's shopping cart
    // and assigns these values to the shopCart array
    // Each value of the shopCart array should be an object like this: {id:random_id, quantity:number_of_products }]
    useEffect(() => {
        let auxCart = []; // auxiliary array that will receive the result of the fetch request
        // postData: performs a POST request with {userId:userId} as the body of the request
        postData('REQUEST1_URL', { userId: userId })
            .then(data => {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.shopCart.length; i++) {
                    auxCart[i] = {};
                    auxCart[i].id = data.shopCart[i].id; //this shopCart is not the same shopCart state variable. Just a value received from the database
                    auxCart[i].quantity = data.shopCart[i].quantity;
                }
            });
        setShopCart(auxCart);
    }, [])
```

After that, I modify *shopCart* by adding attributes/keys with info about the products, such as  product title, price and images:

```
   // Modifies shopCart, which should contain only id's and quantities at the moment, 
    //  assigning details to each product such as price and title.
    // Each value of shopCart should be an object like this:
    // {id:random_id, quantity:number_of_products,
    // title:product_name, price:product_price,
    // oldPrice:old_product_price, image:array_of_images,
    // type:type_of_product}
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect2');
        if (!isFirstRender) { //Ref hook variable used to test if the useEffect is in the first render or not 
            let aux = [...shopCart]; // creates a copy of shopCart
            for (let i = 0; i < shopCart.length; i++) {
                // fetches the details of each product
                fetch('REQUEST2_URL').
                    then(res => res.json()).
                    then(res => {
                        aux[i].image = res[0].image;
                        aux[i].title = res[0].title;
                        aux[i].price = res[0].price;
                        aux[i].oldPrice = res[0].oldPrice;
                        aux[i].type = res[0].type;
                    });
            }
            setShopCart(aux);
        }
    }, [shopCart]);
```

The problem is that the second useEffect keeps printing 'useEffect2' multiple times, showing that it is in a locked loop. How can I fix that ? I was expecting that, since the fetched products info doesn't change, the second useEffect would not be repeating everytime, but it does. I use *shopCart* in its dependecies arrays to **wait** for the first request to finish updating *shopCart*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because inside your second `useEffect`, you have `shopCart` in your dependency array and inside the function you set `shopCart` there, hence it runs infinitely.

You could do all this use case inside the first `useEffect`. How? You could `await` for the first `fetch` to respond and then you for the second request. (You could keep `then()` if you want, but IMO is much cleaner `async...await` way)

Leaving it like:

```
useEffect(async () => {
        let auxCart = []; // auxiliary array that will receive the result of the fetch request
        // postData: performs a POST request with {userId:userId} as the body of the request
        const data = await postData('REQUEST1_URL', { userId: userId })
                for (let i = 0; i < data.shopCart.length; i++) {
                    auxCart[i] = {};
                    auxCart[i].id = data.shopCart[i].id; //this shopCart is not the same shopCart state variable. Just a value received from the database
                    auxCart[i].quantity = data.shopCart[i].quantity;
                }
            let aux = [...shopCart]; // creates a copy of shopCart
            for (let i = 0; i < shopCart.length; i++) {
                // fetches the details of each product
                const res = await fetch('REQUEST2_URL').
                const resData = await res.json();
                        aux[i].image = resData[0].image;
                        aux[i].title = resData[0].title;
                        aux[i].price = resData[0].price;
                        aux[i].oldPrice = resData[0].oldPrice;
                        aux[i].type = resData[0].type;
            }
       // do whatever you want with those objects
    }, [])
```

To make the code much cleaner you could also get rid of those `aux` variables (seems much like imperative programming languages) and start using array functions like `map`, `filter`, etc. depending your need. Indeed in the first `for loop` you are just setting the same values to another array when you could directly use that array:

```
useEffect(async () => {
        const shopCart = await postData('REQUEST1_URL', { userId: userId }).shopCart
            let aux = [...shopCart]; // creates a copy of shopCart
            for (let i = 0; i < shopCart.length; i++) {
                // fetches the details of each product
                const res = await fetch('REQUEST2_URL').
                const resData = await res.json();
                        aux[i].image = resData[0].image;
                        aux[i].title = resData[0].title;
                        aux[i].price = resData[0].price;
                        aux[i].oldPrice = resData[0].oldPrice;
                        aux[i].type = resData[0].type;
            }
       // do whatever you want with those objects
    }, [])
```

And with the second `for..loop` you could also use a `map` but it's a little more complicated since you should use an `async` func inside the `map` and wait for all `Promises` to resolve using `Promise.all()` and it's just a whole new solution... Leaving it for you ;)

Comment: Thanks so much, mate. It's working. I had no idea you could use async await  like that in useEffect. This worked so much better than the way I've been implementing things, that I am actually considering modifying a lot of the codes in this site I'm making. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem at all! You could also do a `map` when doing the `for loop` since you don't need an `auxCart` variable, etc. Editing my answer right now

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things creating the infinite loop in your code. With these 2 things **combined**, it creates the loop.

```
let aux = [...shopCart]; // creates a copy of shopCart
```

<= This action create a plain **new** object, therefore a **new** `shopCart` is always created, making React think it's a different object, even when the content might be the same

```
setShopCart(aux);
    }
}, [shopCart]);
```

<= You are setting this new object to `shopCart`, and as React always think this is a **new** object, it always rerun the `useEffect`

**How to fix this?**

I'm not sure why you split into 2 different `useEffect` and adding the `shopCart` as dependency in the 2nd `useEffect`, but based on what you describe, you can always combine them into one `useEffect`, and use **Promise** or **async/await** to make sure the 2nd API call is only run after the 1st API call finishes. For more detail on this, I think Agustin posted a pretty good example one.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that I had to use the dependency on the second useEffect as a way to wait for shopCart to finish the update in the first useEffect so that I could start the 2nd update. But I used the example with async/await Agustin provided, and it worked much better. I had no idea about this way of implementing things, and it expanded my horizons. Thank you, Jake, for also pointing me in a better direction.